# ArgumentError: In `load': marshal data too short

Tags: ruby

I want to realize multiple processes. I have to send the data which bubble-sorted in different child processes back to parent process then merge data. This is part of my code:

```
rd1,wt1 = IO.pipe # reader & writer

pid1 = fork {
  rd1.close
  numbers = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(copylist[0,p]))
  bubble_sort(numbers)
  sList[0] = numbers.clone
  wt1.write Marshal.dump(sList[0])
  Process.exit!(true)
}

Process.waitpid(pid1)
Process.waitpid(pid2)
wt1.close
wt2.close

pid5 = fork {
  rd5.close
  a = Marshal.load(rd1.gets)
  b = Marshal.load(rd2.gets)
  mList[0] =  merge( a,b).clone
  wt5.write Marshal.dump(mList[0])
  Process.exit!(true)
}
```

There are `pid1`...`pid7`, `rd1`...`rd7`, `wt1`...`wt7`. `pid1`...`pid4` are bubble-sort 4 part of data. `pid5` and `6` merge data from `pid1`, `2` and `pid 3`, `4`. Finally, `pid7` merges the data from `pid5` and `6`.

When data size is small, it succeeds, but when I input larger data  (10000):

```
Data example : 121 45 73 89 11 452 515 32 1 99 4 88 41 53 159 482 2013 2 ...
```

then, errors occur: `：in 'load': marshal data too short (ArgumentError)` and another kind error: `in 'load': instance of IO needed (TypeError)`. The first error line is in `pid5`:  `a = ...` and `pid6`： `b = ...`. The other kind of error line is in `pid7`: `b = ...`. Are my data too big for this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Marshal.load` and `Marshal.dump` work with binary data.  The problem with the short reads is here:

```
a = Marshal.load(rd1.gets)
b = Marshal.load(rd2.gets)
```

`#gets` reads up to a new-line (or end of file) and then stops.  The trouble is that new-line may be present in the binary data created by Marshal.dump.

Change `gets` to `read` in both lines.

Comment: @MudboyZh That's great; you're welcome.  Now that your code works, you might want to submit it to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).  I suspect there are some improvements that could be made to it, but improvements to working code are out of scope here.  CR might be able to help.

Comment: I got a problem. When I input larger size of data (30000 , max is 1000000), it will stuck at  `wt.write....`  Does the method  `write` has something that I have to notice?

Comment: @MudboyZh Please ask this as a new question, with the usual code, sample data, etc.  The new question can link to this question, if you want.

Comment: Sorry! Here is my new question.[Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899876/ruby-multiple-threads-and-processes-get-stuck)