# Ruby multiple threads and processes get stuck

Tags: ruby

I want to compare multiple threads and processes. I have to send the data which bubble-sorted in different child processes back to parent process then merge data. When data size is <= 10000, it succeeds, but when I input larger data ( 50000, 100000, 500000, max to 1000000):

`Data example: 4 152 15 9523 526 1514 2623 ....`

（Fisrt number is 4 for now.The others are just random numbers between 0～10000）

Case 3 will get stuck at the line like this:`wt1.write...` when size is over 50000. If size of data is 500000, even case 1 will be stuck.
Can anybody tell my what's problem in my code ?

This is my code :

```
def bubble_sort(list)
  return list if list.size <= 1
  swapped = true
  while swapped do
    swapped = false
    0.upto(list.size-2) do |i|
      if list[i] > list[i+1]
        list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i] # swap the values
        swapped = true
      end
    end
  end
  return list
end

def mergesort(list)
  return list if list.size <= 1
  mid = list.size / 2
  left  = list[0, mid]
  right = list[mid, list.size-mid]
  merge(mergesort(left), mergesort(right))
end

def merge(left, right)
  sorted = []
  until left.empty? or right.empty?
    if left.first <= right.first
      sorted << left.shift  # take out left first and push back to sorted
    else
      sorted << right.shift
    end
  end
  return sorted.concat(left).concat(right)
end



#------------------------------------------------------------------method
#------------------------------------------------------------------main
#print "Input File Name: "
print "Filename is : "
fName = STDIN.gets.chomp()   # file name
until File.exist?(fName)
  print "Wrong file name! Type again :"
  fName = STDIN.gets.chomp()
end
list = File.read(fName).split(' ').map{ |n| n.to_i}    # File.read() will return string then split by space.
fName.insert(-5,"_output")
k = list[0].to_i             # K is 4 for now
list.delete_at(0)            # delete the K
SizeofInput = list.length    # get the size of input
copylist = list.clone        # copy from list
p = (SizeofInput / k ).to_i  # every part size of input

print "Function Number is (1~4, 0 to exit ): "
fNum = STDIN.gets.chomp().to_i
outFile = File.open(fName,'a+')   # new an output file n
until fNum === 0
  copylist = list.clone
  case fNum
  when 1  # Case 1-----------------------------------------
    puts "#{Time.now}"
    start1 = Time.now
    bubble_sort(copylist)
    stop1  = Time.now
    outFile.write(copylist)
    outFile.write("\nFunc 1 spend time: #{stop1-start1} seconds  Size of input : #{SizeofInput} " + "\n" *5)
    puts "Original Time : #{stop1-start1} seconds. Size of input : #{SizeofInput} "


  when 2  # Case 2------------------------------------------
    sList = Array.new(k) { Array.new()} # sorted list
    puts "#{Time.now}"
    start2 = Time.now
    threads = (0..k-1).map do |i|
      if  i == k-1
        numbers = copylist[i*p..SizeofInput-1].clone# copy the origin array by converting into byte stream
      else
        numbers = copylist[i*p,p].clone# copy the origin array
      end
      Thread.new(i) do |i|
        bubble_sort(numbers)
        sList[i] = numbers.clone
      end
    end

    threads.each{|t| t.join} # => This line will spend lot of time?!
                             # => main thread waits for child threads

    mList = Array.new(k/2) {Array.new()}
    thr = (0...k/2).map do |i|
      Thread.new(i) do |j|
      mList[j] =  merge(sList[j*2],sList[(j*2 )+ 1]).clone
      end
    end
    thr.each{|t| t.join}
    copylist = merge(mList[0],mList[1]).clone
    stop2  = Time.now
    outFile.write(copylist)
    outFile.write("\nFunc 2 spend time: #{stop2-start2} seconds  Size of input : #{SizeofInput} " + "\n" *5)
    puts "Spent time: #{stop2 - start2 } seconds. Size of Input : #{copylist.length}"
  when 3  # Case 3-------------------------------------------

    sList = Array.new(k) { Array.new()}

    rd1,wt1 = IO.pipe # reader & writer
    rd2,wt2 = IO.pipe
    rd3,wt3 = IO.pipe
    rd4,wt4 = IO.pipe
    rd5,wt5 = IO.pipe
    rd6,wt6 = IO.pipe
    rd7,wt7 = IO.pipe
    puts "#{Time.now}"
    start2 = Time.now
    pid1 = fork {
      puts "1 starts"
      rd1.close
      numbers = copylist[0,p].clone
      bubble_sort(numbers)
      sList[0] = numbers.clone
      wt1.write sList[0] #Marshal.dump(sList[0])
      puts "1 is ok"
      Process.exit!(true)
    }
    pid2 = fork {
      puts "2 starts"
      rd2.close
      numbers = copylist[p,p].clone
      bubble_sort(numbers)
      sList[1] = numbers.clone
      wt2.write sList[1] #Marshal.dump(sList[1])
      puts "2 is ok"
      Process.exit!(true)
      exit
    }
    pid3 = fork {
      puts "3 starts"
      rd3.close
      numbers = copylist[2*p,p].clone
      bubble_sort(numbers)
      sList[2] = numbers.clone
      wt3.write sList[2] #Marshal.dump(sList[2])
      puts "3 is ok"
      Process.exit!(true)

    }
    pid4 = fork {
      puts "4 starts"
      rd4.close
      numbers = copylist[3*p..SizeofInput-1].clone
      bubble_sort(numbers)
      sList[3] = numbers.clone
      wt4.write sList[3] #Marshal.dump(sList[3])
      puts "4 is ok"
      Process.exit!(true)

    }


    mList = Array.new(k/2) {Array.new()}
    Process.waitpid(pid1)
    Process.waitpid(pid2)
    wt1.close
    wt2.close
    puts "Finish Pid1 & 2"
    pid5 = fork {
      rd5.close
      a = ( rd1.read.delete '[]').split(%r{,\s*}).map{ |n| n.to_i}  # Marshal.load(rd1.read)
      b = ( rd2.read.delete '[]').split(%r{,\s*}).map{ |n| n.to_i} # Marshal.load(rd2.read)
      mList[0] = merge(a,b).clone
      wt5.write mList[0] #Marshal.dump(mList[0])
      Process.exit!(true)
    }

    Process.waitpid(pid3)
    Process.waitpid(pid4)
    wt3.close
    wt4.close
    puts "Finish Pid3 & 4"
    pid6 = fork {
      rd6.close
      a = (rd3.read.delete '[]').split(%r{,\s*}).map{ |n| n.to_i} #Marshal.load(rd3.read)
      b = (rd4.read.delete '[]').split(%r{,\s*}).map{ |n| n.to_i} #Marshal.load(rd4.read)
      mList[1] =  merge(a,b).clone
      wt6.write mList[1] #Marshal.dump(mList[1])
      Process.exit!(true)
    }

    Process.waitpid(pid5)
    Process.waitpid(pid6)
    wt5.close
    wt6.close
    puts "Finish Pid5 & 6"
    pid7 = fork {
      rd7.close
      a = (rd5.read.delete '[]').split(%r{,\s*}).map{ |n| n.to_i} #Marshal.load(rd5.read)
      b = (rd6.read.delete '[]').split(%r{,\s*}).map{ |n| n.to_i} #Marshal.load(rd6.read)
      copylist = merge(a,b)
      puts "7 is ok"
      wt7.write copylist #Marshal.dump(copylist)
      Process.exit!(true)
    }
    Process.waitpid(pid7)
    puts "Finish Pid7"
    wt7.close
    stop2 = Time.now
    outFile.write(rd7.read) #Marshal.load(rd7.read))
    outFile.write("\nFunc 3 spend time: #{stop2-start2} seconds  Size of input : #{SizeofInput} " + "\n" *5)
    puts "Spent time: #{stop2 - start2 } seconds. Size of Input : #{copylist.length}"

  when 4  # Case 4-------------------------------------------
    sList = Array.new(4) { Array.new() } # sort list
    start3 = Time.now
    (0..3).map do |i|
      if  i === 3
        numbers = copylist[i*p..SizeofInput-1].clone # copy the origin array
      else
        numbers = copylist[i*p,p].clone
      end
      sList[i] = bubble_sort(numbers)
    end

    mList = Array.new(2) { Array.new() } # merge lsit
    (0..1).map do |t|
      mList[t] = merge(sList[t*2],sList[t*2+1]).clone
    end
    copylist = merge(mList[0],mList[1]).clone
    stop3 = Time.now
    outFile.write(copylist)
    outFile.write("\nFunc 4 spend time: #{stop3-start3} seconds  Size of input : #{SizeofInput} " + "\n" *5)
    puts "Spent time: #{stop3 - start3 } seconds. Size of Input : #{copylist.length}"

  else  puts "Wrong Number!! Try Again!"
  end

  print "Function Number is (1~4, 0 to exit ): "
  fNum = STDIN.gets.chomp().to_i

end  # end of until loop
  outFile.close()
  puts "See you again~"
```

Comment: There is no problem but `bubblesort` itself. It is `O(n²)` and on large data it simply takes too long time for you to wait.

Comment: I know,but it ran almost 3 hours. It's still stuck. Thanks for your response.

Comment: As far as I understood, your goal is to measure threads vs. processes, right? That said, you don’t need hours. Just cut your input back to `10_000`.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have to record how long it takes in 4 cases at size 10000, 100000, 500000, 1000000.